# ElasticSearch - creating JDBC river

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I working on a PHP project, Using MYSQL for storing data. I want to use ElasticSearch search engine for searching I installed the ES on my Mac OS. I know after that I should create JDBC river but I don't know how. Any body can help me? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Steps to install [Elasticsearch JDBC River Plugin](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc)

1) Download and install `Elasticsearch`
2) Start `Elasticsearchby` running `bin/elasticsearch` from the installation directory

3) Install the `river-jdbc` plugin for `Elasticsearch` version. You can get jdbc river plugin for your version from [here](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc#installation)

If you are using elaticssearch version 1.0.0 then your installation command will be

```
./bin/plugin --install river-jdbc --url http://bit.ly/1gIk4jW
```

4) Now download the MySQL JDBC driver. The current version is 5.1.30. You can get latest version information from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

5) Copy jar in `elasticsearch/plugins/river-jdbc` direcory

6) Now Restart elasticsearch from your installation directory `bin/elsaticsearch -f`

7) Run below command configure jbdc river with your elasticsearch index.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "select * from yourDBTable",
        "index" : "write_index_name_here",
        "type" : "write_index_type_here"
    }
}'
```

You can use more parameter as per your need more details about [elasticsearch-river-jdbc parameters](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/JDBC-River-parameters)

8) Now test your plugin is up or not using below command

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?pretty&q=*'
```

Comment: there is no plugins folder in elasticsearch folder.

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch you are using? Is `bin` folder there?

Comment: I think after run `./bin/plugin --install river-jdbc --url http://bit.ly/1gIk4jW` command it will create plugin folder directory parallel to bin.

Comment: What should write instead of "write_index_name_here" and "write_index_type_here"?

Comment: Your index name and index type. I hope you already create index and type. If you haven't create index then [please see documentations here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html)

Comment: I did this: curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/jdbc/_meta' -d '{"type":"jdbc","jdbc":{"driver":"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","url":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","user":"","password":"","sql":"select * from orders"},"index":{"index":"jdbc","type","jdbc"}}'

Comment: But when I run curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?pretty&q=*' this, got an error "{"error":"IndexMissingException[[jdbc] missing]","status":404}"

Comment: Is your elasticsearch running on http://localhost:9200 . if it running perfectly then what is your `index` and `type` name?

Comment: I did according this: http://www.asktoapps.com/import-mysql-data-into-elasticsearch/

Comment: I don't know how to create index first?

Comment: I have MYSQL database by the name test and table is orders, I want to implement this in elasticsearch please help me

Comment: What is the index type?

Comment: You can create index type using `curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/orders/order'`. `orders` is name of the index and `order` is your index type. replace index name and type in your jdbc river curl query

Comment: I have done all the steps but elasticsearch is failed to start curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused.

Comment: Please refer this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/connection-refused-error-on-elastic-search)