# Elasticsearch: Failed to connect to localhost port 9200 - Connection refused

Tags: elasticsearch

When I tried connecting to Elasticsearch using the 
`curl http://localhost:9200` it is working fine.

But when I run the `curl http://IpAddress:9200` it is throwing an error saying

> Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

How to resolve this error?

Comment: If you already set **network.host: localhost** in the elasticsearch.yml file then you can try to add the http protocol in the request: `curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200"`

Comment: At least using Elasticsearch 7.8.0 on Windows 10, just uncommenting network.host in the elasticsearch.yml file works for me.

Comment: Be sure to check the log (mine was located at /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

By default it should bind to all local addresses. So, assuming you don't have a network layer issue with firewalls, the only ES setting I can think to check is `network.bind_host` and make sure it is either not set or is set to `0.0.0.0` or `::0` or to the correct IP address for your network.

Update: per comments in ES 2.3 you should set `network.host` instead.

Comment: I had to explicitly set the `network.bind_host` value, leaving it unset was my issue.

Comment: Are you sure this is safe? I think the right is access only from local server.

Comment: Well, in most cases this is safe. But yeah, that's why the clause for "correct IP address for your network" is there.

Comment: As stated below "network.bind_host" is now "network.host" for elasticsearch 2.3

Comment: what are some network commands I should use to check my server settings? if I did netstat -plunt | grep 9200 what should it show?

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus it should show you `LISTEN` in the output. Something like `tcp6       0      0 1.1.1.1:9200       :::*                    LISTEN      12345/java`

`LISTEN` means ES is listening and ready to accept connections. The ideal way to check ES cluster status though is using `curl $HOSTNAME:9200`

Answer (score 99):

Edit `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` and add the following line:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

This will "unset" this parameter and will allow connections from other IPs.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! However on my Mac, the config file is located at `/Applications/elasticsearch-2.1.1/config/elasticsearch.yml`, and the parameter I had to edit was `network.host`, not `network.bind_host`.

Comment: in elasticsearch 2.2 the parameter is called  network.host

Comment: this /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml file should be in Docker container ?

Comment: This solves for me, i'm using elasticsearch-6.0.0 running inside docker container. After the config change, I can now access by `curl http://172.17.0.2:9200`. You will recognize that is the commonly used docker ip addressing.

Comment: network.host: 0.0.0.0 - do not help, but this exception I am getting from cerebro

Comment: For me network.host: 127.0.0.1 and http.port: 9200 is working.
on 0.0.0.0 getting error

Answer (score 34):

In my case elasticsearch was started.
But still had

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

The following command was unsuccessful

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

In order to make it work, I had to run instead

```
sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch
```

Then it went all fine.

Comment: I also had to do `sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch`.

Comment: I got the same issue, but could not understand why `systemctl` works and service does not ?

Comment: @Luv33preet systemctl is powered by systemd and is an entirely different program

Comment: I get the error message: sudo: systemct1: command not found

Answer (score 29):

Tried everything on this page, and only instructions from [here](https://lxadm.com/Problems_starting_elasticsearch_in_Ubuntu_16.04) helped.

in `/etc/default/elasticsearch`, make sure these are un-commented:

```
START_DAEMON=true
ES_USER=elasticsearch
ES_GROUP=elasticsearch
LOG_DIR=/var/log/elasticsearch
DATA_DIR=/var/lib/elasticsearch
WORK_DIR=/tmp/elasticsearch
CONF_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch
CONF_FILE=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
RESTART_ON_UPGRADE=true
```

make sure `/var/lib/elasticsearch` is owned by elasticsearch user:

```
chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch/
```

Comment: Had the same problem and the solution was just `chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch/` and un-commented the `START_DAEMON=true`

Answer (score 20):

Why don't you start with this command-line:

```
$ sudo service elasticsearch status
```

I did it and get:

```
"There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime..."
```

Then I edited `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` file:

```
...

################################################################

# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

#-Xms2g
#-Xms2g

-Xms512m
-Xmx512m

################################################################

...
```

This worked like a charm.

Comment: This appears to give the same information as the 22 March answer bu @Jefferson.macedo. A new answer should not just rewrite existing details, it should provide new and usefil information.

Comment: @AdrianHHH actually this answer provide new information such as the error obtained and comments on the meaning of **-Xmxxx** lines. I think the "original" answer is less attractive somehow, possibly because the quotes of code are NOT separated from the text, being placed in the middle of the text instead.

Answer (score 18):

None of the proposed solutions here worked for me, but what eventually got it working was adding the following to `elasticsearch.yml`

```
network:
  host: 0.0.0.0
http:
  port: 9200
```

After that, I restarted the service and now I can `curl` it from both within the VM and externally. For some odd reason, I had to try a few different variants of a `curl` call *inside* the VM before it worked:

```
curl localhost:9200
curl http://localhost:9200
curl 127.0.0.1:9200
```

Note: I'm using Elasticsearch 5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 14):

Edit `elasticsearch.yml` and add the following line

```
http.host: 0.0.0.0
```

`network.host: 0.0.0.0` didn't work for

Comment: this worked for me as well thanks! this solution ran on ES `7.17.13` and ubuntu `20.04`

Answer (score 13):

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000085330000, 2060255232, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

be sure that the server is started. I've seen this problem when my virtual machine had too litle RAM and es could not start.

```
sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
```

the above will show you if es is indeed running.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447434/elasticsearch-memory-probles for help sorting this problem out.

Answer (score 11):

For this problem, I had to use : 
`sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch start`

to be able to get something on ports 9200/9300 (sudo netstat -ntlp) and a response to:

`curl -XGET http://localhost:9200`

Comment: checking the status, the error message doesnt help. only when running the bin file manually it's giving correct error message.

Answer (score 6):

I experienced a similar issue.

**Here's how I solved it**

Run the service command below to start **ElasticSearch**

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

If you still get the error

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

Run the service command below to check the status of **ElasticSearch**

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
```

If you get a response (**Active: active (running)**) like the one below then you **ElasticSearch** is active and running

> ● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
>      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      **Active: active (running)** since Sat 2019-09-21 11:22:21 WAT; 3s ago

You can then test that your **Elasticsearch** node is running by sending an HTTP request to port 9200 on localhost using the command below:

```
curl http://localhost:9200
```

Else, if you get a response a different response, you may have to debug further to fix it, but the running the command below, will help you detect what caveats are holding **ElasticSearch** service from starting.

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
```

If you want to stop the **ElasticSearch** service, simply run the service command below;

```
sudo service elasticsearch stop
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch
```

**N/B:** You may have to run the command `sudo service elasticsearch status` **OR** `sudo systemctl status elasticsearch` each time you encounter the error, in order to tell the state of the **ElasticSearch** service.

This also applies for **Kibana**, run the command `sudo service kibana status` **OR** `sudo systemctl status kibana` each time you encounter the error, in order to tell the state of the **Kibana** service.

That's all.

**I hope this helps.**

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem refusing connections on 9200 port.
Check elasticsearch service status with the command `sudo service elasticsearch status`. If it is presenting an error and you read anything related to Java, probably the problem is your jvm memory. You can edit it in `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`. For a 1GB RAM memory machine on Amazon environment, I kept my configuration on:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx128m
```

After setting that and restarting elasticsearch service, it worked like a charm. Nmap and UFW (if you use local firewall) checking should also be useful.

Comment: This is what did it for me. My config had 1g for both, and the AWS instance (t2.micro) couldn't allocate that much memory to it. The start and restart commands failed silently, but the status command detailed the error.

Answer (score 3):

Open your **Dockerfile** under **elasticsearch** folder and update **"network.host=0.0.0.0"** with **"network.host=127.0.0.1"**. Then restart the container. Check your connection with curl.

```
$ curl http://docker-machine-ip:9200
{
  "name" : "vI6Zq_D",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "hhyB_Wa4QwSX6zZd1F894Q",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.2.0",
    "build_hash" : "24e05b9",
    "build_date" : "2017-01-24T19:52:35.800Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For versions **higher** than **6.8** *(7.x)* you need two things.

#### 1. change the network host to listen on the public interface.

In the configuration file `elasticsearch.yml` (for **debian** and derivatives -> `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`).

- set the `network.host` or `network.bind_host` to:

```sh
...
network.host: 0.0.0.0
...
```

> Or the interface that must be reached

#### 2. Before going to production it's necessary to set important discovery and cluster formation settings.

According to elastic.co:
[v6.8](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/discovery-settings.html) -> discovery settings that should set.
by e.g

```sh
...
# roughly means the same as 1
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: -1
...
```

[v7.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/discovery-settings.html) -> discovery settings that should set.
by one single node

```sh
discovery.type: single-node
#OR set discovery.seed_hosts : 127.0.0.1:9200
```

> at least one of [**discovery.seed_hosts**, **discovery.seed_providers**, **cluster.initial_master_nodes**] must be configured.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows user try,

```
https://localhost:9200/
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This was the reason for my case too. I am using a mac

Answer (score 1):

In this case, first of all you need to check the java version using below command:

```
java -version
```

after running this command you get something like this:

> java version "1.7.0_51"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.5.5.el7-x86_64 u51-b31)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

then use this command:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

and select the below version

> *+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51-2.4.5.5.el7.x86_64/jre/bin/java
>      2           /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_73/jre/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 2

```
curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents,

I just followed the install procedure on Digital Ocean, apparently the package available in the repos is not up to date, I deleted everything and followed the install procedure direct from Elastic Search and everything is working now, basically the out of the box behaviour is on a localhost pointing to 9200. Same thing/issue found with Kibana, the solution for me was too, to remove everything and just follow their procedure, Hope this saves someone two hours (the time I spent figuring out how to setup ELK!)

en

Answer (score 1):

Update your jdk to latest minimum version for your elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

Change the network.bind to 0.0.0.0 and http:port to 9200. The bind address 0.0.0.0 means all IPv4 addresses on the local machine. If a host has two IP addresses, 192.168.1.1 and 10.1.2.1, and a server running on the host listens on 0.0.0.0, it will be reachable at both of those IPs.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter the **Connection refused** error, simply run the command below to check the status of ElasticSearch service

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
```

This will help you decipher the state of ElasticSearch service and what to do about it.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you installing ELK on virtual machine in GCP (Google Cloud Platform), make sure that you created firewall rule of `Ingress` type (i.e. for incoming to VM traffic). You can specify in the rule multiple ports at a time by separating them with comma: `5000,5044,5601,9200,9300,9600`.

In that rule you may want to specify a tag (pick tag's name as you like, for example `docker-elk` that will target your VM (Targets column):
[image]

On VM's settings page assign that tag to your VM:

[image]

After doing that I was able to access Elasticsearch in my browser via port 9200. And I didn't have to edit `elasticsearch.yml` file whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I have run across this problem every time I install or upgrade ES (7.0+). And the solution was ALWAYS just wait for ES to fully start. It takes about a minute for the REST API to be reponsive. No matter what service status says.

```
service elasticsearch start
*started

*wait for at least a minute

curl now works and returns responses on the port 9200
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04, but I purged the downloaded elasticsearch directory and then redownloaded so,

First Pipe the output to the gpg --dearmor command so that apt is able to utilise the key to verify downloaded packages

```
curl -fsSL https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/elastic.gpg
```

Then, add the Elastic source list to the sources.list.d directory, where apt will search for new sources

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/elastic.gpg] https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
```

Afterwards update package lists and install elasticsearch again

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install elasticsearch
```

When you finish the download, you need to modify main configuration file elasticsearch.yml where most of its configuration options are stored

```
sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

And then navigate to the Netwok section something like

```
. . .
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------

#
network.host: Foo.foo.foo
. . .
```

**Elasticsearch listens for traffic from everywhere on port 9200. You will want to restrict outside access to your Elasticsearch instance to prevent outsiders from reading your data or shutting down your Elasticsearch cluster through its [REST API]**

So replace the Foo.foo.foo with

```
. . .
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
network.host: localhost
. . .
```

I used localhost so that Elasticsearch listens on all interfaces and bound IPs.

Start elasticsearch and enable it each time the server starts

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch
```

With all that said you will have to configure the firewall to allow access to the default Elasticsearch HTTP API port (TCP 9200) for the trusted remote host, generally the server you are using in a single-server setup, such as198.51.100.0. To allow access, type the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow from 198.51.100.0 to any port 9200
sudo ufw enable
```

Use cURL to test your installation

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

Response

```
{
  "name" : "elastic-22",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "DEKKt_95QL6HLaqS9OkPdQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.17.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "e5acb99f822233d62d6444ce45a4543dc1c8059a",
    "build_date" : "2022-02-23T22:20:54.153567231Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.11.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After utilizing some of the answers above, don't forget that after an apt install, a total reboot might be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on this, I've came across many docs through google that said to set network.host to localhost.

Doing so gave me the infamous connection refused. You must use an IP address (127.0.0.1), not a FQDN.

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that port `9200` is open for my case it was an amazon instance so when i opened it in my security group the curl command worked.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling SELinux worked for me, although I don't suggest it - I did that just for a PoC

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I could not work with `localhost` I needed to set it to localhost's IP address

`network.bind_host: 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem is with java version, i installed `open-jdk 11` previously. Thats creating the issue while starting the service. I changed it `open-jdk 8` and it started working

Answer (score 0):

you  have to  edit /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
by default all configurations will be commented  ,add following configuration

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: [0.0.0.0]
```

then restart the service

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this on CentOS 7, and the issue was that /etc/hosts had the following:

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain

which I updated to include localhost as follows:

127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain

after that, no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a related situation recently.
Here's my take on the subject: [Accessing Elastic 5.5 in vagrant guest from host through a private network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74900324/accessing-elastic-5-5-in-vagrant-guest-from-host-through-a-private-network)

TL;DR
The settings:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
```

work fine. One just needs to wait enough time for ES to complete its initialization procedure, bind to the network iface and start listening on the port.

Now, from within the guest, `curl http://localhost:9200` works and from the host, `curl http://192.168.54.2:9200` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the network host was explicitly set to the IP of my server, so it was something like this in `opensearch.yml`:

```
network.host: 127.150.151.0
```

I had to configure my app to use this IP explicitly. Otherwise, I could also have changed the address in `opensearch.yml`.