# How to bind Elasticsearch 2.0 on both Loopback and Non-Loopback interfaces?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Starting from version 2.0 Elasticsearch binds only on the loopback interface by default (**_local_** in terms of configuration).

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/modules-network.html) says that there is a way to switch to another network, for example, **_non_loopback_** binds to the first non-loopback interface. It works fine.

But I cannot figure out how do I combine these settings so that Elasticsearch binds on *both* loopback and non-loopback interfaces simultaneously?

PS. My reason is that I use Logstash on each Elasticsearch instance that connects to it via localhost, but I also want other Elasticsearch instances to see each other to form the cluster...

Comment: This might be doable using [transport profiles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html#_tcp_transport_profiles) but I haven't tried yet.

Comment: @Val, thank you for the suggestion, but according to the reference transport profiles are only for node-to-node communication... Of course, I can still use non-localhost IP address for Logstash configuration, but it would make configuration maintenance much worse than it is used to be in 1.x.

Comment: @Funbit how do you connect LS to ES?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Using this: hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"] . As I said, I could include ethernet IP here, but I would have to do that for each instance separately.. since Logstash does not support environment/dynamic variables in its configuration.

Comment: @Funbit what protocol are you using with LS? Assuming `http` (since port 9200)

Comment: @AndreiStefan Not sure how it is related to the problem, but: I'm using "tcp" input, and "elasticsearch" output. LS 2.0 (which I'm trying to use with ES 2.0) supports only "http" protocol.

Comment: Ok. Then try in your ES something like the following. Remove any `network.bind*` and `network.publish*` settings from your `elasticsearch.yml` file and add `transport.host: _non_loopback_` and  
`http.host: _local_`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan This way I will lose ability to connect to ES instances from Kibana or Browsers... I dont want to install reverse proxy just for that..

Comment: Try another config and see how it goes: `network.bind_host: 0`

Comment: @AndreiStefan The magic worked! Thank you! Please post an answer I'll mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For 2.0 you would need to use

```
network.bind_host: 0
```

Comment: This solved my question too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691858/elasticsearch-nonodeavailableexception

Comment: What would be the solution for 2.3.2 ? I did the same as mentioned above but still the problem persists.

Comment: Worked for ES5!

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/31677628/154461 I think you must use network.host instead of network.bind_host for version >= 2.3

Answer (score 8):

As of ElasticSearch 7.x, this configuration has changed yet again.  for a simple single node cluster bound to loopback, local and external IPs, you essentially do this:

```
network.host: [_local_, _site_, _global_]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: node-1
```

The cluster node setting is explained [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/problems-with-access-to-elasticsearch-form-outside-machine/172450/2) while the network host setting is in the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html), although it doesn't say how you would assign multiple values to `network.host`.

Answer (score 2):

Go to

```
'<path_to_elasticsearch>/elasticsearch-2.3.4/config'
```

Open `elasticsearch.yml`

Add
      `network.host: 0.0.0.0`

Now check which port elasticsearch is using (`9200` is default), go to firewall inbound rules and add those ports.