# Elasticsearch distant access

Tags: elasticsearch

my Elasticsearch is installed on azure virtual machine.
works fine locally in :

```
http://localhost:9200/
```

how to use it from outside ?

thanks

Comment: Install it onto your public server and then access it via: [YOUR-IP]:9200 ?

Answer (score 1):

Within your Elasticsearch.yml configuration you have to change your Network part.

It's the setting: **network.host:**

default value set to local (localhost) and you may apply the following 4:

1. *local* Any loopback addresses on the system
2. *site* Any site-local addresses on the system
3. *global* Any globally-scoped addresses on the system
4. *[networkInterface]* Addresses of a network interface, for example *en0*

So inside the same network use site, while from a different network you should use global. But as stated in the docu - be carefull exposing unprotected nodes to the public...

taken from the official [docu](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html), further details are also available there.

---

EDIT: I found the same question for elasticserach version 2.0
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696944/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-request-in-elasticsearch-2-0?rq=1) that refers to the following [docu](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/setup-configuration.html) part of elasticsearch.

In the docu is written that

```
network :
    host : 10.0.0.4
```

is also an applicable syntax to specifiy the adress.