# How to access Elasticsearch IP:Port on local machine from Hyper-V VM

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elk

I have a setup of elasticsearch-7.14 on my `windows10` `local machine`. I am able to access the `elasticsearch` [ES] url from local machine's browser on:

**1.** `localhost:9200`
**2.** `192.168.x.x:9200` [local machine IP]

**But I am not able** to access the ES (`192.168.x.x:9200`) from my hyper-V Ubuntu VM's (running on same machine ) browser.

**Debugging:**

1. **ES setup command:** `docker run --name es01-test --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0`
2. `ping 192.168.x.x` **is working** from my VM
3. `curl -vvv 192.168.x.x:9200` is **not** working from my VM
4. `elasticsearch.yml` inside ES docker container was already having `network.host: 0.0.0.0` written.
5. I tried all combinations of configs in `elasticsearch.yml` answered in [link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696944/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-request-in-elasticsearch-2-0/44240227#44240227) & [link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33438638/13134795) but still not able to access ES from VM.

```
    transport.host: localhost 
    transport.tcp.port: 9300 
    http.port: 9200
    network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

6. After changing `elasticsearch.yml` I am doing `docker restart ES-Container-ID` so that yml changes are read, but still not able to access ES from VM.
7. I have `openssh-server` installed on my VM

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue? Have the same.

Comment: No @Adam. I dropped this setup and installed all setup on one VM with high RAM and disk storage capacity. You can answer to this if you are able to achieve