# Elasticsearch 2.3 enable access from outer ip

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch installed on my host.

Request from localhost works fine

```
 curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/
```

But how can I configure elasticsearch.yml in order to connect from one outer ip?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412549/how-to-bind-elasticsearch-2-0-on-both-loopback-and-non-loopback-interfaces

Comment: Thank you @Val It works for me

Comment: One more question: If I use option like in mentioned question (network.bind_host: 0) ES listen requests from any host. How can I specify host list?

Comment: [from the official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html): "Accepts an IP address, hostname, a special value, or an array of any combination of these."

Comment: Maybe something wrong with syntax, but this `network.bind_host: 0` works fine. But neither `network.bind_host: ["192.168.56.1", "127.0.0.1"]` nor `network.bind_host: [192.168.56.1, 127.0.0.1]` doesn't. `[FAIL] elasticsearch is not running ... failed!` Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `elasticsearch.yml` file, locate the line `#network.host:`, uncoment it (remove the "#") and change to `network.host: 0.0.0.0`

Then add the exception to the firewall and reload it (In my case I use UFW, so I ran `sudo ufw allow 9200` and `sudo ufw reload`)

**Obs**: Tested on version: 2.3

Comment: Thank you. Can I add particular ip address (not broadcast 0.0.0.0)?

Comment: @AlexZhulin I've tried using my server's external ip address and it worked, so I guess you can...