# Elasticsearch - Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I tried to install Elasticsearch and run it.

When I type `curl -X GET http://localhost:9200` or `curl -X GET 192.1.0.0:9200`, I get this error:

> Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

How may I fix this?

I searched Stack Overflow for this issue, but none of the solutions worked for me, including this one: [Elasticsearch: Failed to connect to localhost port 9200 - Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/connection-refused-error-on-elastic-search)

I also found [this article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/modules-plugins.html),  tried to follow it, but failed,
because every time I type this in my cmd:

```
bin/plugin --install mobz/elasticsearch-head
bin/plugin --install lukas-vlcek/bigdesk
```

cmd will tell me:

> plugin is not recognized as internal or external command

How do I fix this one?

Comment: cmd? Are you running Elasticsearch on Windows? bin/plugin won't work because directories use backslashes. And are you sure Elasticsearch is running?

Comment: @Fiskie ya im running it on windows. idk its run or not, due to localhost:9200 actively refused by machine, i guess my elasticsearch is not working yet.

Answer (score 1):

use https://localhost:9200/ instead of http://localhost:9200

For more info check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73842343/9947525

**But**

the best solution is to use Docker Image of ELK stack which is easy instead of downloading the E L K and then run on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

`Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused` usually means that ElasticSearch is not running.

1. Try to start ElasticSearch by running `elasticsearch-x.x.x/bin/elasticsearch`.
2. The start log should contain no error messages, and say something like

   ```
   [2017-11-28T23:38:39,356][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport]
   [okCzlUj] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200},
   bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9200}, {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
   ```
3. Make sure your start log also says ElasticSearch is running on port 9200 as above.