# Elasticsearch is not running in browser

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-20.04

I have downloaded the Elasticsearch 8.1 in my Ubuntu. After successful installation, when I execute

```
curl -u elastic https://127.0.0.1:9200 -k
```

It is showing expected elasticsearch response. But when I hit `http://127.0.0.1:9200/` or `http://localhost:9200` in my browser, it is returning

[image: Error response]

After installation, I added `network.host: 127.0.0.1` to `elasticsearch.yml`

Can anybody help me, why it is not running in browser ?

I am using Ubuntu 20 OS & following this [Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/8.0/get-started-elastic-stack.html#_make_sure_that_elasticsearch_is_up_and_running)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 8.0, Elasticsearch [security is turned on by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/release-highlights.html#_security_features_are_enabled_and_configured_by_default) and SSL/TLS is required for HTTP communications.

There are at least two options:

1. call `https://` - as you did successfully via `curl`
2. disable HTTP security, but that's discouraged.

Comment: I cannot run in browser any longer ?

Comment: You can but using `https://` instead of `http://` and have your browser trust the self-signed certificate that is created by default

Comment: Thanks a lot, in my case i'm looking to experimenting locally, so this works like a charm @Val

Answer (score 1):

I am using the windows platform, the steps are the same. When you run the elasticsearch.bat in cmd

[image]

use this port for elasticsearch HTTPS secure https://localhost:9200/

check the username and password scroll down the cmd running elasticsearch
[image]

After login into the elasticsearch. Hurry...

[image]

Thanks

**But**

the best solution is to use Docker Image of ELK stack which is easy instead of downloading the E L K and then run on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

just put this url :

```
https://localhost:9200/
```

It run on the https, I hope it is helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Like others mentioned, from version 8.0 security is turned on by default. But if you just want to quickly set up elasticsearch locally (and so security is not a concern) you can [disable security](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cannot-disable-security-in-8-1/299857):

1. go into `config` folder
2. open the `elasticsearch.yml` file and paste the following lines at the end:

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: false
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: false
```

3. finally just restart elasticsearch

Now you should be able to open http://127.0.0.1:9200 without login prompts (in the browser) and curl/postman, etc and get proper 200 responses.