# Why Doesn't Elasticsearch connect to LocalHost:9200?

Tags: python, macos, elasticsearch, localhost, local

thanks for your help.

I downloaded Elastic Search and in the terminal of my mac,
it says that the status is green.

[image: green status terminal]

But if I type in to my browser: localhost:9200 it says "the connection was reset" on Firefox and "This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" on Chrome.

Kibana also downloaded correctly and I was able to get into the localhost:5601 no problem where I can see the ES interface I think I am supposed to see.

Why can't I access localhost:9200? I tried this in jupyter and got a false return:
[image: Jupyter]

Maybe there is a hint right here in the terminal shortly after the status changed from yellow to green? lines of code that say WARN keep repeating...
[image: Warn terminal?]

Could really use some help on this please, am a total noob with ES but really want to learn! Thank you!

UPDATE: @Sagar Patel Here is what my yml file looks like. Definitely has to be some issue in here that is causing the problem. (I switched my network host to .0.0.0.0 as suggested in the thread provided by @fuzzy_logic).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/elasticsearch-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-9200-connection-refused), few different things there to try. Maybe try start with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/elasticsearch-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-9200-connection-refused/45070395#45070395).

Comment: Can you please show configuration of elasticsearch.yml file

Comment: Btw @Jack, thanks a lot for the complete question. In the future I feel it is best if text file are not screenshot but snippets. It makes it easier for all of us to search, copy and paste ....

Answer (score 6):

## Tldr;

In you last screen shot we can the the following error `... received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection ...`

Your Elasticsearch seems to be expecting `Https` and not `http`

## To fix

```py
es = Elasticsearch("https://localhost:9200"
    verify_certs=False) # <- Optional, only if you face issue with verifying the certificate
```

Comment: Hi @Paulo! Tried this and it didn't work :/ think the issue may be yml related

Comment: Hey @Jack this might not be the only issue but looking at your logs and your yml file. You are definitely using `https` So I do think it is part of your issue.

Comment: I think the issue with my certificate. 
curl --cacert $ES_HOME/config/certs/http_ca.crt -u elastic https://localhost:9200 %                        (base) jackgreenberg@Jacks-MacBook-Pro elasticsearch-8.2.2 % curl --cacert $ES_HOME/config/certs/http_ca.crt -u elastic https://localhost:9200

Comment: What did this command output ?

Comment: Hi @Paulo, I lost the command output. I think the issue based on the error log is something with an ssl not being configured in the yml:

uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: invalid configuration for xpack.security.transport.ssl - [xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled] is not set, but the following settings have been configured in elasticsearch.yml : [xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password,xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.secure_password]

Comment: (base) jackgreenberg@Jacks-MacBook-Pro elasticsearch-8.2.2 % curl --cacert $ES_HOME/config/certs/http_ca.crt -u elastic localhost:9200
Enter host password for user 'elastic':
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200 after 0 ms: Connection refused

Comment: maybe use the flag -v to get more information but again... you are not using HTTPS on curl ... maybe try that at some point

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the windows platform.

try to use [https://localhost:9200/][1] instead of http://localhost:9200

For more details kindly check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73842343/9947525

**But**

the best solution is to use Docker Image of ELK stack which is easy instead of downloading the E L K and then run on the local machine.
[1]: https://localhost:9200/