# After restarting all of my cluster nodes getting error Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

I am using Elasticsearch 2.3 with Debian 8, cluster of 3 nodes in google cloud platform. Now i tried to enable dynamic scripting using below lines of code in elasticsearch.yml

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: false
```

Now in order to reflect the changes in all nodes i tried to restart all 3 nodes by writing below command on all 3 nodes terminal.

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

Now the problem i am facing is now when i am trying to write any elasticsearch query in terminal i am getting below error on all of my 3 nodes.

```
curl http://localhost:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

Now can anyone please tell me as i have restarted every node why none of my nodes are running on port 9200. I think the error is somewhere in restarting my cluster that's why i think "sudo service elasticsearch restart" does not restarted my ES server successfully. Now can some one please enlighten my why "sudo service elasticsearch restart" is not working for me OR if this is not the proper way to restart the node cluster then what actually is ??

**Also when i tried to run below command i got this error**

```
golumyntra@elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-09-09 18:36:25 UTC; 1h 11min ago
Docs: http://www.elastic.co
Process: 5289 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.pidfile=${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid -
Des.default.path.home=${ES_HOME} -Des.default.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Des.default.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Des.defau
lt.path.conf=${CONF_DIR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 5286 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/
  SUCCESS)
Main PID: 5289 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.new...4)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files...2)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settin...7)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.Internal...8)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.in...2)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.in...1)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearc...5)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: Refer to the log for complete error details.
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=ex...URE
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

**Also when i tried to run below command to getting elasticsearch status i got this error**

```
golumyntra@elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm:~$ sudo service elasticsearch status
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-09-09 18:36:25 UTC; 1h 16min ago
Docs: http://www.elastic.co
Process: 5289 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.pidfile=${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid 
-Des.default.path.home=${ES_HOME} -Des.default.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Des.default.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Des.def
ault.path.conf=${CONF_DIR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 5286 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0
  /SUCCESS)
Main PID: 5289 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.ne...4)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(File...2)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setti...7)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.Interna...8)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.i...2)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.i...1)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsear...5)
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm elasticsearch[5289]: Refer to the log for complete error details.
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=e...URE
Sep 09 18:36:25 elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

My **elasticsearch.yml** is given below

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: false
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please see the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: elasticsearch-cluster
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: "elasticsearch-cluster-3-vm"
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
# node.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
# path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
# bootstrap.mlockall: true
#
# Make sure that the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable is set to about half the memory
# available on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
# http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html>
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.140.0.8", "10.140.0.7", "10.140.0.9"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of nodes / 2 + 1):
#
# discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
# gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-gateway.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Disable starting multiple nodes on a single system:
#
# node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
# action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Below is the Log File **elasticsearch-cluster.log**

```
[2016-09-09 17:34:17,440][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] version[2.3.4], pid[48
03], build[e455fd0/2016-06-30T11:24:31Z]
[2016-09-09 17:34:17,447][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] initializing ...
[2016-09-09 17:34:18,641][INFO ][plugins                  ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] modules [reindex, lang
-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-09-09 17:34:18,685][INFO ][env                      ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] using [1] data paths, 
mounts [[/elasticsearch (/dev/sdb)]], net usable_space [9.1gb], net total_space [9.7gb], spins? [possibly], typ
es [ext4]
[2016-09-09 17:34:18,686][INFO ][env                      ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] heap size [1015.6mb], 
compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-09-09 17:34:18,686][WARN ][env                      ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] max file descriptors [
65535] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
[2016-09-09 17:34:23,869][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] initialized
[2016-09-09 17:34:23,870][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] starting ...
[2016-09-09 17:34:24,010][INFO ][transport                ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] publish_address {10.14
  0.0.8:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
  [2016-09-09 17:34:24,020][INFO ][discovery                ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] elasticsearch-cluster/
  KrC2l77BSxWBkp9SaTPiUQ
  [2016-09-09 17:34:25,605][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] stopping ...
  [2016-09-09 17:34:25,622][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] stopped
  [2016-09-09 17:34:25,622][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] closing ...
  [2016-09-09 17:34:25,632][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] closed
  [2016-09-09 17:34:26,714][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] version[2.3.4], pid[49
  04], build[e455fd0/2016-06-30T11:24:31Z]
  [2016-09-09 17:34:26,716][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] initializing ...
  [2016-09-09 17:34:27,610][INFO ][plugins                  ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] modules [reindex, lang
  -expression, lang-groovy], plugins [license, marvel-agent], sites []
  [2016-09-09 17:34:27,638][INFO ][env                      ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] using [1] data paths, 
  mounts [[/elasticsearch (/dev/sdb)]], net usable_space [9.1gb], net total_space [9.7gb], spins? [possibly], typ
  es [ext4]
  [2016-09-09 17:34:27,639][INFO ][env                      ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] heap size [1015.6mb], 
  compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
  [2016-09-09 17:34:27,640][WARN ][env                      ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] max file descriptors [
  65535] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
  [2016-09-09 17:34:30,764][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] initialized
  [2016-09-09 17:34:30,767][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] starting ...
  [2016-09-09 17:34:30,880][INFO ][transport                ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] publish_address {10.14
    0.0.8:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
    [2016-09-09 17:34:30,886][INFO ][discovery                ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] elasticsearch-cluster/
    bbFuynfLSMuPNveLrhdf8A
    [2016-09-09 17:34:33,942][WARN ][discovery.zen            ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] failed to connect to m
    aster [{elasticsearch-cluster-3-vm}{7Q2pD7oFSKmsmhTlaVqiVQ}{10.140.0.9}{10.140.0.9:9300}], retrying...
    ConnectTransportException[[elasticsearch-cluster-3-vm][10.140.0.9:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: ConnectE
    xception[Connection refused: /10.140.0.9:9300];
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:987)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:920)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:893)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:260)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.joinElectedMaster(ZenDiscovery.java:434)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.innerJoinCluster(ZenDiscovery.java:386)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.access$4800(ZenDiscovery.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$JoinThreadControl$1.run(ZenDiscovery.java:1237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /10.140.0.9:9300
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:152)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)  
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    ... 3 more
    [2016-09-09 17:34:36,978][WARN ][discovery.zen            ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] failed to connect to m
    aster [{elasticsearch-cluster-3-vm}{7Q2pD7oFSKmsmhTlaVqiVQ}{10.140.0.9}{10.140.0.9:9300}], retrying...
    ConnectTransportException[[elasticsearch-cluster-3-vm][10.140.0.9:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: ConnectE
    xception[Connection refused: /10.140.0.9:9300];
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:987)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:920)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:893)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:260)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.joinElectedMaster(ZenDiscovery.java:434)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.innerJoinCluster(ZenDiscovery.java:386)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.access$4800(ZenDiscovery.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$JoinThreadControl$1.run(ZenDiscovery.java:1237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /10.140.0.9:9300
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:152)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    ... 3 more
    [2016-09-09 17:34:40,779][INFO ][marvel.agent.exporter    ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] skipping exporter [def
    ault_local] as it isn't ready yet  
    [2016-09-09 17:34:41,855][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] detected_master {elast
      icsearch-cluster-3-vm}{LBnGmCW6RRikUqEZPzejjw}{10.140.0.9}{10.140.0.9:9300}, added {{elasticsearch-cluster-3-vm
      }{LBnGmCW6RRikUqEZPzejjw}{10.140.0.9}{10.140.0.9:9300},{elasticsearch-cluster-2-vm}{NgAty4rhS5a35208Ive-vw}{10.
        140.0.7}{10.140.0.7:9300},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [{elasticsearch-cluster-3-vm}{LBnGmCW6RRikUq
          EZPzejjw}{10.140.0.9}{10.140.0.9:9300}])
        [2016-09-09 17:34:41,879][INFO ][http                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] publish_address {10.14
          0.0.8:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
          [2016-09-09 17:34:41,880][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] started
          [2016-09-09 17:34:41,888][WARN ][discovery.zen            ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] master_switched_while_
          finalizing_join, current nodes: {{elasticsearch-cluster-3-vm}{LBnGmCW6RRikUqEZPzejjw}{10.140.0.9}{10.140.0.9:93
            00},{elasticsearch-cluster-2-vm}{NgAty4rhS5a35208Ive-vw}{10.140.0.7}{10.140.0.7:9300},{elasticsearch-cluster-1-
              vm}{bbFuynfLSMuPNveLrhdf8A}{10.140.0.8}{10.140.0.8:9300},}
              [2016-09-09 17:34:41,984][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] detected_master {elast
                icsearch-cluster-3-vm}{LBnGmCW6RRikUqEZPzejjw}{10.140.0.9}{10.140.0.9:9300}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from mas
                  ter [{elasticsearch-cluster-3-vm}{LBnGmCW6RRikUqEZPzejjw}{10.140.0.9}{10.140.0.9:9300}])
                [2016-09-09 17:34:42,744][INFO ][license.plugin.core      ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] license [f47ae398-a8f7
                -4197-bb34-6ceae7443c8f] - valid
                [2016-09-09 17:34:42,747][ERROR][license.plugin.core      ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm]
                #
                # License will expire on [Sunday, October 09, 2016]. If you have a new license, please update it.
                # Otherwise, please reach out to your support contact.
                #
                # Commercial plugins operate with reduced functionality on license expiration:
                # - marvel
                #  - The agent will stop collecting cluster and indices metrics
                #  - The agent will stop automatically cleaning indices older than [marvel.history.duration]
                [2016-09-09 18:36:24,359][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] stopping ...
                [2016-09-09 18:36:24,531][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] stopped
                [2016-09-09 18:36:24,531][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] closing ...
                [2016-09-09 18:36:24,543][INFO ][node                     ] [elasticsearch-cluster-1-vm] closed
```

Below is the Log File **elasticsearch.log**

```
[2016-07-27 06:55:15,454][INFO ][node                     ] [Cold War] version[2.3.4], pid[20240], build[e455fd0
/2016-06-30T11:24:31Z]
[2016-07-27 06:55:15,460][INFO ][node                     ] [Cold War] initializing ...
[2016-07-27 06:55:16,772][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Cold War] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-g
roovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-07-27 06:55:16,822][INFO ][env                      ] [Cold War] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)
]], net usable_space [7.2gb], net total_space [9.7gb], spins? [unknown], types [rootfs]
[2016-07-27 06:55:16,827][INFO ][env                      ] [Cold War] heap size [1015.6mb], compressed ordinary
object pointers [true]
[2016-07-27 06:55:16,827][WARN ][env                      ] [Cold War] max file descriptors [65535] for elastics
earch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
[2016-07-27 06:55:21,718][INFO ][node                     ] [Cold War] initialized
[2016-07-27 06:55:21,731][INFO ][node                     ] [Cold War] starting ...
[2016-07-27 06:55:21,947][INFO ][transport                ] [Cold War] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_a
ddresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-07-27 06:55:21,966][INFO ][discovery                ] [Cold War] elasticsearch/NpR2fn7ZSaqwTdo32BTRrw
[2016-07-27 06:55:25,104][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Cold War] new_master {Cold War}{NpR2fn7ZSaqwTdo32BT
  Rrw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
  [2016-07-27 06:55:25,156][INFO ][http                     ] [Cold War] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_a
  ddresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
  [2016-07-27 06:55:25,159][INFO ][node                     ] [Cold War] started
  [2016-07-27 06:55:25,197][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Cold War] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
  [2016-07-27 06:55:26,355][INFO ][node                     ] [Cold War] stopping ...
  [2016-07-27 06:55:26,371][INFO ][node                     ] [Cold War] stopped
  [2016-07-27 06:55:26,372][INFO ][node                     ] [Cold War] closing ...
  [2016-07-27 06:55:26,395][INFO ][node                     ] [Cold War] closed
```

**Finally i got the solution, the error was my easticsearch user not had permissions to folder etc/elasticsearch. Now there is just one doubt should i add elasticsearch user to www-data group and give permission or should i add my user to elasticsearch group. Both are same thing but i am wondering in future may be coz of this any problem might happen**.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please go through below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/connection-refused-error-on-elastic-search

Comment: I have already looked at that answer and as you can see i have already set network.host: 0.0.0.0 also  "curl http://localhost:9200" AND "curl http://IPAddress:9200" none is working for me thanks anyways.

Comment: `[Connection refused: /10.140.0.9:9300]` - this is your error. Is this address correct?

Comment: address is correct but i don't know why it is trying to connect on port 9300 because every of my nodes are running on port 9200.

Answer (score 0):

go to dir  /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml and add the following line:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: sorry but not working, you can see my elasticsearch.yml its already there. thanks anyways

Comment: do you know how should i start my ES cluster properly, is it right to write "sudo service elasticsearch restart" to every node to restart the whole cluster.

Comment: @Praksh Kumar http.port: 9200  why this line is commented ?

Comment: was commented by default should i uncomment it.

Comment: i have changed http port to 9200 of all of my 3 nodes but when i try to start it using "sudo service elasticsearch restart" OR "sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start" getting same error on all of my nodes Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

Comment: kill all the process ES if your using linux

Comment: i wrote these two commands "sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10","sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start" and again tried to connect to my elasticsearch but getting same error.

Comment: i am using Debian 8

Comment: please help me i am facing this problem from past 3 weeks

Comment: curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_shutdown' try this  from the master node only if not sucessfull then try this curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9300/_shutdown'

Comment: OR use can this comands                                                                       sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
sudo /bin/systemctl start elasticsearch.service                                                              or sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch

Comment: I tried on all of my nodes both commands, still getting same connection refused error.

Comment: finally i got the solution, the error was my easticsearch user not had permissions to folder etc/elasticsearch. Now there is just one doubt should i add elasticsearch user to www-data group and give permission or should i add my user to elasticsearch group. Both are same thing but i am wondering in future may be coz of this any problem might happen