# Elastic search on AWS site can’t be reached

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticsearch

I have elastic search running on my AWS Server, I follow [this tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-elasticsearch-on-aws):
And, when I execute this on my server:

```
$ curl localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
```

And returns the correct results.

But, when I use the complete IP provider by Amazon, I get the error:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> 52.33.201.250 refused to connect.

Also, my configuration is: [image]

What other thing I need do to configure it?

Comment: That looks correct I think. Are you sure that security group is assigned to your ES server? EDIT to say, check that your ES config allows remote connections

Comment: 100% sure @Andy

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/connection-refused-error-on-elastic-search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

In your `"/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml"`

Set your public or private ip according to your needs: `network.host: your_ip`

Comment: Well, is not the `public ip`, is the `Private IPs` provider by amazon (but not the public, in my case `170.xx.xx.xx`

Comment: Thanks @MrMins. Yes its `Private IP` for me instead of `Public IP`