# Sending requests to ElasticSearch service running on EC2 instance

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I'm a beginner to AWS and ElasticSearch, and am playing around with ElasticSearch in the hopes of understanding more about how I could potentially use it in production. I know that AWS has its own ElasticSearch product, but I wanted to spin up my own EC2 instance and set up ElasticSearch myself just to learn more about it.

I've gotten ElasticSearch up and running on my EC2 instance by following [elastic.co's instructions](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-elasticsearch-on-aws). I started my ES service and executed a curl command:

```
$ curl localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
```

I got back a valid response:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

However, I've been trying to send the same request remotely, and am timing out:

```
curl http://MY-EC2-INSTANCE-IP-ADDRESS:9200/_cluster/health?pretty

curl: (7) Failed to connect to XX.XX.XXX.XX port 9200: Operation timed out
```

When I created my EC2 instance, I made sure to specify an HTTP option within my security group. I've attached a screenshot below:
[image]

Moreover, I've also tested to make sure that HTTP actually is working. I started up my own little Apache server using `service httpd start`, and placing a small `index.html` file in `/var/www/html`, with a simple

> Hello, this is an elastic search.

text filler. When I visit my EC2 instance IP address, I get the correct index.html text rendered:

[image]

I know AWS' own ElasticSearch service provides the endpoint directly for the user, with no port number (or at least a default port number). But there's surprisingly very little documentation on how to send requests to remote ES services (almost all of them have `localhost:9200` as the example).

What is the proper protocol for sending requests to an ElasticSearch service on an EC2 instance?

Comment: I think you misunderstood some things. A security group is a firewall. When you are inside the instance via ssh, you are also inside the firewall and therefore able to freely access any port on `localhost`. Security group settings have 0 effect there. Once outside the security group you have to pass the firewall. Now what really counts is the port number and TCP vs UDP. In your case, you'll need to add a "Custom TCP Rule" for port 9200. "HTTP" is merely a shortcut to specify TCP on port 80 and not needed to reach an elasticsearch server on port 9200, even though it also uses the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Thank you. This is extremely helpful. If you go ahead and write this as an answer I can accept it as he most comprehensive and best explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer after scouring a few SO posts, ultimately arriving at a solution by Kimberly W in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/connection-refused-error-on-elastic-search). In my `elasticsearch.yml`, edit the following configurations:

```
network:
  host: 0.0.0.0
http:
  port: 9200
```

Then, go to your AWS Security group settings and edit your inbound rule to include:

[image]

This will allow incoming connections to `9200`.

Then, restart the ElasticSearch service. The key issue is that I'm pinging the correct location, but if no one is listening to port 9200, then no one will respond.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to open port 9200 in your security group. Your example is connecting using port 9200.

Comment: Thanks. How come I'm able to connect to the ElasticSearch service then via `localhost` to port 9200 with no problems?

Comment: Woops- nevermind. I interpreted your answer incorrectly. You were saying I need to add port 9200 for HTTP to the inbound security group.