# Cannot connect to elasticsearch on docker from golang

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm using olivere's elastic go library (https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5) to create a connection to elasticsearch like so:

```
addr = "http://172.17.0.2:9200"
client, err := elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetURL(addr))
```

and am getting this error:

```
health check timeout: no Elasticsearch node available
```

Elasticsearch is running in a docker container and I am able to curl it from both my local machine and from the docker container. However, the go code (running on the docker container) is not able to connect to it.

```
curl -s -XGET 'http://172.17.0.2:9200/_nodes/http?pretty=1'
{
  "_nodes" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : {
    "pGBN2DBISgSZ8hd9lFgmHw" : {
      "name" : "pGBN2DB",
      "transport_address" : "127.0.0.1:9300",
      "host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
      "version" : "5.6.4",
      "build_hash" : "8bbedf5",
      "roles" : [
        "master",
        "data",
        "ingest"
      ],
      "http" : {
        "bound_address" : [
          "0.0.0.0:9200"
        ],
        "publish_address" : "172.17.0.2:9200",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes" : 104857600
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Docker for Mac. The publish address and IP are off, not sure if that has something to do with it. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Edit /`etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` to add the following line:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

This will allow connections from other IPs.

Possible duplicate of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/connection-refused-error-on-elastic-search)

Comment: you will also need to add `discovery.type: single-node` or `discovery.seed_hosts : ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"]`