# VPC connectivity to VPC Elasticsearch cluster port 9200 unresponsive

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, vpc

I'm trying to set up a centralized logging solution that uses filebeat on EC2 to ship logs directly to a VPC AWS Elasticsearch cluster (simple configuration, no logstash). I do not require any internet accessibility to Elasticsearch.

My VPC is `172.31.0.0/16`
My Access Control Policy is wide open (which is only to the VPC)
My security groups allow TCP `443` and `9200`

On the EC2 instance, I'm able to get a response from the https endpoint

```
curl https://vpc-<my-es-cluster>.<region>.es.amazonaws.com
{
  "name" : "<name>",
  "cluster_name" : "<account-id>:<my-es-cluster>",
  "cluster_uuid" : "<uuid>",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.2.2",
    "build_hash" : "10b1edd",
    "build_date" : "2018-02-28T15:42:08.616107Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.2.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

From my EC2 instance 9200 is unavailable, which seems like a security group issue, however the sg attached to my domain allows `443` and `9200` from `172.31.0.0/16`. I also tried opening the attached sg up to all traffic and that did not resolve my issue.

I did some research and found that this issue may be due to not setting the `network.host` configuration on the ES cluster to bind to `0.0.0.0` (or the private IP): [Connection refused error on Elastic Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/connection-refused-error-on-elastic-search)

Has anyone else run into this issue?  This is a basic use case: an EC2 within a VPC failing to have network access to a VPC-internal ES cluster over 9200 despite an open security group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should us the port 80 I think, not 9200.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Filebeat was using 9200 by default, so I had to specify `http://<url>:80` as my `output.elasticsearch` `hosts` in `/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml`