# Elasticsearch Connection refused when connect

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I try install elasticsearch.
I use cmd `sudo service elasticsearch status` to check status

```
● elasticsearch.service - LSB: Starts elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since T5 2020-07-09 08:56:26 +07; 2min 7s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 8437 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8470 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Th07 09 08:56:26 bach-Vostro-3650 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts elasticsearch...
Th07 09 08:56:26 bach-Vostro-3650 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts elasticsearch.
```

seem like it ok.

But when i go to `http://127.0.0.1:9200/`,it result:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9200: Connection refused
```

I try setting `network.host: 0.0.0.0` it don't work for me

How do fix this solve. Thanks All.

Comment: The property is network.host and not host.network, can you check that once?

Comment: sorry, miss typing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elasticsearch: Failed to connect to localhost port 9200 - Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/elasticsearch-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-9200-connection-refused)

Comment: i try all evething solve in above link, but don't work for me

Comment: @BáchNguyênTrần is your ES process running?

Comment: @BáchNguyênTrần i just post the answer if you not find it useful let me know, I will update it. please share your elasticsearch.yml and elasticsearch.rb file also ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem.

in your elasticsearch.yml just add these lines

```
  development: &default
  host: elasticsearch
  log: true
```