# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused elasticsearch is unable to start or load

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-20-04) to install Elasticsearch on Ubuntu 20.04 (LEMP). When I run:

```
curl 'localhost:9200'
```

I get this error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

Whenever I run: `sudo -i service elasticsearch start` the command takes around 20 minutes to finish, the server goes 504 Gateway Time-out until the commands ends, and it ends with the below error:

```
Job for elasticsearch.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I have edited `sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` to no avail.

When I run `journalctl -xe` I get the below long screen. I appreciate it if anyone can please give me a pointer about how to fix this issue. I tried [every scenario on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/elasticsearch-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-9200-connection-refused) and none worked.

[image]

Running `journalctl -f --unit elasticsearch` gives the below:

```
Jul 31 06:09:03 Domain.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
Jul 31 06:09:03 Domain.com systemd-entrypoint[40315]: 2021-07-31 04:09:03,074610 UTC [40315] INFO  Main.cc@106 Parent process died - ML controller exiting
Jul 31 06:18:46 Domain.com systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Jul 31 06:18:49 Domain.com systemd-entrypoint[41903]: encountered [2] errors parsing [/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options]
Jul 31 06:18:49 Domain.com systemd-entrypoint[41903]: [1]: encountered improperly formatted JVM option in [/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options] on line number [33]: [ -Xms2g]
Jul 31 06:18:49 Domain.com systemd-entrypoint[41903]: [2]: encountered improperly formatted JVM option in [/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options] on line number [34]: [ -Xmx2g]
Jul 31 06:18:49 Domain.com systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 31 06:18:49 Domain.com systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 31 06:18:49 Domain.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
Jul 31 06:21:43 Domain.com systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
```

`jvm.options` file include:

```
################################################################
##
## JVM configuration
##
################################################################
##
## WARNING: DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. If you want to override the
## JVM options in this file, or set any additional options, you
## should create one or more files in the jvm.options.d
## directory containing your adjustments.
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/jvm-options.html
## for more information.
##
################################################################



################################################################
## IMPORTANT: JVM heap size
################################################################
##
## The heap size is automatically configured by Elasticsearch
## based on the available memory in your system and the roles
## each node is configured to fulfill. If specifying heap is
## required, it should be done through a file in jvm.options.d,
## and the min and max should be set to the same value. For
## example, to set the heap to 4 GB, create a new file in the
## jvm.options.d directory containing these lines:
##
## -Xms4g
## -Xmx4g
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html
## for more information
##
################################################################


################################################################
## Expert settings
################################################################
##
## All settings below here are considered expert settings. Do
## not adjust them unless you understand what you are doing. Do
## not edit them in this file; instead, create a new file in the
## jvm.options.d directory containing your adjustments.
##
################################################################

## GC configuration
8-13:-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
8-13:-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
8-13:-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly

## G1GC Configuration
# NOTE: G1 GC is only supported on JDK version 10 or later
# to use G1GC, uncomment the next two lines and update the version on the
# following three lines to your version of the JDK
# 10-13:-XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC
# 10-13:-XX:-UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
14-:-XX:+UseG1GC

## JVM temporary directory
-Djava.io.tmpdir=${ES_TMPDIR}

## heap dumps

# generate a heap dump when an allocation from the Java heap fails; heap dumps
# are created in the working directory of the JVM unless an alternative path is
# specified
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# specify an alternative path for heap dumps; ensure the directory exists and
# has sufficient space
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch

# specify an alternative path for JVM fatal error logs
-XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log

## JDK 8 GC logging
8:-XX:+PrintGCDetails
8:-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
8:-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
8:-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
8:-Xloggc:/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log
8:-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
8:-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32
8:-XX:GCLogFileSize=64m

# JDK 9+ GC logging
9-:-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
```

The following is the content of the `elasticsearch.yml` file:

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
network.host: localhost
#network.host: localhost
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Comment: What about the output given by `journalctl -f --unit elasticsearch`? Can you share it?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question and added that there to the end of the question. I think the error is related to the memory size. Right?

Comment: I tried to change and uncomment the memory size in  `jvm.options` file in `/etc/elasticsearch` but that did not work.

Comment: Can you show your /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options file?

Comment: Yes, sure. I have added that above and update the ticket.

Comment: It looks like it is unmodified, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is unmodified and line 34 is this line: `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html` which I find strange. (!)

Comment: I noticed that the `elasticsearch` file permissions in `etc` is `rwxr-s---`. Do you think I have to change this?

Comment: I also posted the content of `elasticsearch.yml` file.