# Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://localhost:9200

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I trying to install ELK (this resource https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/elasticsearch-and-kibana-installation-and-basic-usage-on-ubuntu-1604/) but when I open my web browser and use `http://localhost:5601` URL to test if it has been installed correctly i receive two errors
[image]

I test all response [Elasticsearch: Failed to connect to localhost port 9200 - Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/elasticsearch-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-9200-connection-refused) but did not work
and this is my `elasticsearch.yml`

```
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
network.host: 127.0.0.1:5601
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
```

when i run `sudo systemctl status elasticsearch` i get blew result

```
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-09-29 14:23:36 +0330; 4m>
       Docs: http://www.elastic.co
    Process: 69262 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-syst>
    Process: 69263 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PI>
   Main PID: 69263 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

سپتامبر 29 14:23:33 samira-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsear>
سپتامبر 29 14:23:33 samira-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearc>
سپتامبر 29 14:23:33 samira-System-Product-Name elasticsearch[69263]: OpenJDK 64>
سپتامبر 29 14:23:36 samira-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: elasticsearch.servic>
سپتامبر 29 14:23:36 samira-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: elasticsearch.servic>

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
```

this is my log
[image]
How can i fix this?

Comment: We would need the logs from elasticsearch

Comment: that's a _very_ old version of Elasticsearch and Kibana. If you're looking to just play with it, you may want to try the docker images: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html. If you're looking for install instructions for newer Debian packages: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html

Comment: I updated it but again I get this errors@Russ Cam

Answer (score 0):

I can see your elasticsearch.yml and identified few corrections which you can try and restart you elastic search instance.

1. network.host: 127.0.0.1               ----> no need of port number and most important **5601** is for kibana.
2. Elastic search uses default http port number 9200 if you are running multiple es instances on single machine(practice) you can define http port number in increasing order. It ranges from 9200 to 9299.

#http.port: 9200         ------> You can comment/uncomment for single instance, doesn't matter.